# how can i know remote device is cisco switch or router with php?

Tags: php, cisco

I dont know if this topic can be written in this forum but if i am wrong warn me.Let's go my question...
How can i know remote device is cisco or other companies' switch or router device by using php(sockets) by using send SNMP or connecting witth telnet?I dont want php codes but i want to know if this type of operation can be done or not.If it can,which way is the best?Sending SNMP or connecting with telnet on 23th port or the way you suggest.
Thanks for advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming you have permission, and you have the correct SNMP username/passwords, a request of `SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0` will give you

> A textual description of the entity. 
>    This value should include the full name and version identification of
>    the system's hardware type, software operating-system,
>    and networking software.

see [Cisco MIB here](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&mibName=SNMPv2-MIB)

This should meet your needs.

PHP has a [snmpget method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.snmpget.php) that sounds like what you need.

If you don't have network permission, then I suggest you download nmap, and study how it identifies host operating systems.

Comment: Thanks,i will look at snmpget method of php.Your suggestions will be useful for me